# How to delete all the files in the folder INCLUDE the sub-folder?

Tags: java, file, directory, delete-file

This is my code. But it only be able to delete the txt file in the current folder, not sub-folder.

```
import java2.org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
    import java.io.*;
    public class DeleteSameType{
    public static void main(String []args){

        File dir = new File("user/document/test");
        FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter); 
        for(File f: files){
            f.delete();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.delete() does not delete directories which are not empty. You need to create a recursive function to delete files from directory and subdirectories.

```
import java2.org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
    import java.io.*;
    public class DeleteSameType{
    public static void main(String []args){

    DeleteSameType deleteSameType = new DeleteSameType();

        File dir = new File("user/document/test");

    deleteSameType.recursiveDelete(dir)        

    }

    private void recursiveDelete( File dir) {

    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt");
    if(dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
          for(File f: files){
                recursiveDelete(f);
        } 

        }
    dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u elaborate more on the recursive method? I am a beginner for algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @Jeetendra That's great code, get a good sample of recursive method !

Comment: @Jeetendra, This is a redundant code IMO, as Java framework provides utilities to recursively list all files under a directory.

Answer (score 1):

After trying I find this code is better than the recursive method:
We should use [listFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean))

```
package deletefile;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class DeleteFile {
    public static void main(String []args){  
        File dir = new File("/Users/Documents/test");
            String [] str = {"docx"};
           Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(dir,str,true);   
           for(File f:files){
               f.delete();
           }
    }
 }
```

remember to add "/" before your Directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem with [File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) is that it does not list recursively.

You can use [FileUtils.listFiles](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)) which uses one filter for files and one filter for the directories, and specify `TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE` in `dirFilter` to match all subdirectories.

Comment: This is my code
                `FileUtils.listFiles(dir,FileFilterUtils.NameFileFilter("txt"),TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);` but not seem not work, can u elaborate more?

Comment: The problem is that the second parameter we must put exact name, cannot use wildcard

Comment: The prototype of `FileUtils.listFiles` is `public static Collection<File> listFiles(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter, IOFileFilter dirFilter)`. Therefore, the second parameter in your code can be `new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt")` as `WildcardFileFilter` class implements `IOFileFilter `.